# Regex. Как выделить все строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно выделить все строки между словами v_.*
Но выделяются только первые строки.
Пример https://regex101.com/r/KLf3x9/1

Comment: `/^(?!v_).+?(?=v_)/gms`